# Telegram Bot that says "Hi"

Tags: python, telegram

I'm trying to make a very simple Telegram Bot in Python that says "Hi" every minute. This is the code so far, but it does not post anything to my telegram.

```py
import requests
import time

bot_token = "insert_token_here"
group_chat_id = "insert_group_chat_id_here"

def send_message(chat_id, text):
    url = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{bot_token}/sendMessage"
    payload = {
        "chat_id": chat_id,
        "text": text
    }
    requests.post(url, data=payload)

while True:
    send_message(group_chat_id, "Hi")
    time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: Show the response of Telegram please

Answer (score 0):

You can give it a try, but make sure you installed "python-telegram-bot" through pip/pip3.

```
import logging
from telegram import Bot
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackContext
from datetime import datetime
import time

# Set your Telegram Bot Token here
TOKEN = "YOUR_TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN"

# Set your chat_id (replace with your chat_id)
CHAT_ID = "YOUR_CHAT_ID"

# Enable logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Define the function to send "Hi" message
def send_hi_message(context: CallbackContext):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=CHAT_ID, text="Hi!")

def start(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text('Bot is running!')

def main():
    # Create the Updater and pass it your bot's token
    updater = Updater(token=TOKEN)

    # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    # Register the command handler
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))

    # Use the JobQueue to schedule the 'send_hi_message' function every minute
    j = updater.job_queue
    j.run_repeating(send_hi_message, interval=60, first=0)

    # Start the Bot
    updater.start_polling()

    # Run the bot until you send a signal to stop (Ctrl+C)
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Replace "YOUR_TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN" and "YOUR_CHAT_ID" with your actual Telegram bot token and chat ID.

Comment: "C:\Users\oscar\PycharmProjects\Solana Price Bot\.venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:\Users\oscar\PycharmProjects\Solana Price Bot\nft_bot.py" 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\oscar\PycharmProjects\Solana Price Bot\nft_bot.py", line 45, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\oscar\PycharmProjects\Solana Price Bot\nft_bot.py", line 26, in main
    updater = Updater(token=TOKEN)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Updater.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'token'

Process finished with exit code 1